# Sync photos in Adobe Lightroom CC

Tags: lightroom, adobe, sync, creative-cloud

I have been using Lightroom CC for some time now and I have grown familiar that all my pictures and work are uploaded and synced to the Cloud.
While I enjoy the benefits that come with this behaviour (e.g. working from multiple devices easily), more recently I haven't been able to upload new pictures in Lightroom CC as the application complains that my local hard drive is full.
While that is true, I have also noticed that there is plenty of space available in the Cloud.

Therefore, I suspect that all my pictures are synced to the Cloud and all my devices are syncing those locally.

If that was the case, however, considering that all my devices have modest disk size (about 128GB each), it would mean I would never be able to make proper use of the 1TB Cloud space that comes with my Lightroom CC license.

In the ideal world, I would have expected to have the Cloud storing all my pictures and work while on my devices I would be able to sync only those pictures which are relevant to me at a given point in time.

Is there any way I can customise the sync settings of a Lightroom CC instance running in one of my devices so that it will sync locally only selected part of my work? For example, if I wish to work on a picture or an album, I only wish to sync that one, I don't need to sync everything.
Is that possible in Abode Lightroom CC?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming Lightroom Classic in my answer, as this will display the phenomenon, whereas Lightroom should not.. Please clarify which version you are actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming Lightroom Classic for this...

Synchronisation services are not backup services or offline storage services. Many people make the same mistake with such as iCloud.
A synchronisation service enables multiple devices to share the same data. Removing data from one device will remove it from all synchronised devices.
You can therefore only sync as much data as you have space for locally.

From Adobe - [How does sync work in Lightroom Classic?](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-classic/kb/sync-faq.html)

> **My desktop is running out of space if I turn on sync in Lightroom Classic. What should I do?**
>
> Lightroom Classic downloads original images from the cloud if sync is
> turned on. If you have a considerable number of images on the cloud,
> it may take space on your local hard disk.
>
> **Can I delete images from Lightroom Classic after syncing it with the cloud?**
>
> If you delete images from Lightroom Classic after syncing it with the
> cloud, the images will be deleted from the cloud as well.

For Lightroom [cloud version] then you can set local storage allocation in prefs - see [Lightroom | Local Storage Preferences](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom-cc/using/preferences.html#Localstoragepreferences)

Comment: Thanks, fyi the question is specific for Lightroom CC (the Cloud version of Lightroom)

Comment: OK. The cloud version should be smart enough to look after itself, but have a look at the prefs link. I can't attest to exactly how it works as I don't use cloud structures for anything important. I prefer to be in charge of my own destiny re versioning, backups, distribution etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Lightroom CC's preferences, go to "Local Storage", where you can select how much you want it to save locally to your computer. The dialog looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am assuming I should adjust that percentage value, I should give that a try - thought the description "Use photo cache size equal to x% of your remaining disk space" is a bit misleading, how much space does it actually take on disk? And is the idea that Lightroom CC will automatically make sure to never exceed that?